# Interview follow up on Class Design by avoiding diamond case

Tags: java, uml

Recently I have been asked design question. There are two classes Horse and Bird. I need to design new class called Unicorn which is having all the methods of class Horse and Bird.

```
Horse          Bird
     |         |
       Unicorn
```

Since in Java we cant extend two classes (to avoid diamond problem) how do we achieve this?

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it OK to make Horse and Bird interfaces? You are allowed to implement several interfaces in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Façade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to achieve this. Your unicorn class would contain instances of both Bird and Horse and implement the relevant methods by calling them on these contained instances.

Answer (score 0):

In Java a class can not extend multiple classes, but an interface can extend multiple interfaces.

Before going into class level design, first create two interfaces Horse and Bird, then create the interface Unicorn which will extend both the interfaces.